# Dropdown margin in bootstrap navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How do I align the bootstrap `navbar drop-down`?  The drop down always starts from the right corner, is it possible to set the starting point for the `drop-down`.

[image: example]

Here is [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gvw7j/10/).

Both the menu when I click always starts from the right. Is it possible to move the first menu drop drown to some margin left? The drop down should start from the menu where its clicked rather than from entirely right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this CSS

CSS

```
.navbar .nav>li {
  position: relative;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gvw7j/12/)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you are using Bootstrap 2.1, but you are missing `.dropdown` class on your `<li>` which suppose to have dropdown.

```
<li class="dropdown">
  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
    <b class="caret"></b>
  </a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li class="nav-header">Nav header</li>
    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```